# Call Procedure to Set New Class

Tags: vb.net

I have a dropdown which when the user click, it will tell whether it is a parent/child type. The type will later be used to filter the dropdown value. The parent/child type is obtained using a class called PrmNode. This class will pull all sort of information related to the dropdown. How can I set the parent/child value when new PrmNode is created. I'm not familiar with get/set properties using the class. Here's what I have so far:

Declaration:

```
    Private _DDParent As PrmNode
    Private _DDChildren As List(Of PrmNode)
```

Properties:

```
    Friend Property DropDownParentOfThisParameter() As PrmNode
    Get
        Return _DDParent
    End Get
    Set(value As PrmNode)
        _DDParent = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property DropDownChildrenOfThisParameter() As List(Of PrmNode)
    Get
        Return _DDChildren
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of PrmNode))
        _DDChildren = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly Property DropDownChildrenCount() As Integer
    Get
        If _DDChildren Is Nothing Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return _DDChildren.Count
        End If
    End Get
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly Property DropDownChildren(ByVal Idx As Integer) As PrmNode
    Get
        If _DDChildren Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        ElseIf Idx < _DDChildren.Count Then
            Return _DDChildren(Idx)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
    End Property
```

When a new PrmNode is created, it will call the code below which is pulling the information from database:

```
    Friend Sub New(ByRef sqlR as SqlDatareader, ByVal CID as integer)
```

I'm assuming that I need to set the _DDParent and _DDChildren inside the procedure above, but I'm just lost here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing her, but it seems that a `TreeView` might be more appropriate for your user interface.

Comment: @Blackwood i don't think treeview works for dropdown. I have a list of field name and when you click that name, it will used the stored information and pull value from database to be inserted to a dropdown. What I'm trying to do is when field 'A' is click and it is identified as the parent, it will use the selected value to filter the child drop down. The codes above should store the class information so when the field name is clicked, it will have direct reference to any of the parent or children.